# firebase Refer Child by user given id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase-database.

[image: Firebase database]

```
 Query lastQuery = databaseReference.child("rawlocations").child("12345678").limitToLast(1);

lastQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    Double latt= (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
    Double lngg= (Double) dataSnapshot.child("lng").getValue();
    LatLng location=new LatLng(latt,lngg);
});
```

In this database locations are updating for every 10 meters.Now i want to refer the very recently updated location?How can i refer this in my code?Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the latitude and longiture of a single id, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference idRef = rootRef.child("raw-locations").child("12345678");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
            double lng = ds.child("lng").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", lat + " / " + lng);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
idRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

If you want all ids, you need to loop twice.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference rawRef = rootRef.child("raw-locations");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                double lat = dSnapshot.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                double lng = dSnapshot.child("lng").getValue(Double.class);
                Log.d("TAG", lat + " / " + lng);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
rawRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thank You So much

Comment: Sorry i had explained wrongly.Actually i want to refer by another dynamic variable in place of "12345678" which is a id entered by the user.So u can help me? How can i do this?

Comment: i want to refer by any dynamic variable in the place of "12345678" which is enterd by the user of the app at login time how can i refer in this my code? can u help me?

Comment: I don't understand what  do you mean with `dynamic variable`? Give me a concrete example.

Comment: Actually i want to refer the locations of that current id.Each user had seperate id's.For example ,if u and me installed my application (app) means both we have separate id's That app take Your location corresponds to your id and if i login with my id means it would show my location.So in the code if we put any one id will always shows that id location only.So i want refer with a variable means it is easy to access with all id's.Can u help me?

Comment: If you want `"Actually i want to refer the locations of that current id"` use the first option. If you want all the locations of all ids, please use the second option. Have you try id? Does it work?

Comment: Sorry Dude,I didn't know to explain my concept to you clearly.I don't know even it is possible or not for my project?

Comment: Try your best. I'll mine.

Comment: can you share your Facebook id .can i talk to in private in a clear manner?

Comment: We can start a conversation here. We can also help other users.

Comment: ok brother I feel not comfortable in this since i was not know more about this i would also like to say i am very new to android and firebase. So only i asked like that.

Comment: Ok I had cleared the above mentioned issue.Now i had new issue.I want to refer the very recently updated location.How can i refer in my code?can u help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works in my code and feth every value from my childs

```
 mDatabase.child("raw-locations").child("12345678").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    final List<String> lstItems= new ArrayList<String>();

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String name = (String) ds.getKey();
                            String values = (String) ds.getValue();
                            Log.e("Values",""+values );
                            lstItems.add(values );

                        }
```

also you can change this line

```
String values = (String) ds.getValue();
```

with this

```
String Latvalue = (String) ds.child("lat").getValue();
```

Comment: Thanku but i want to take for all id's